# How to apply Multiple CSS Property for a html div in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html div which has its basic css property at first, but when user clicks on a button, i want to change that div's  more than one CSS property in one line

In below, I want to apply multiple css property to the image "MotionS" only when moveRight(); is called in Script itself.

```
            <html>

             <head>
         <title>JavaScript Animation</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        var imgObj = null;
        var animate ;

        function init(){
           imgObj = document.getElementById('motionS');
           imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
           imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
        }

        function moveRight(){
            document.getElementById('motionLess').style.visibility='hidden';
            document.getElementById('motionS').style.visibility="visible;height:50px;width:40px";

           imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
           animate = setTimeout(moveRight,200); // call moveRight in 20msec
        }

        function stop(){
           clearTimeout(animate);
           imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
        }

        window.onload =init;

        </script>

         </head>

        <body>

        <form>
       <img id="motionLess" src="../Downloads/micky-steal.jpg" alt="micky-steal" style="height:120px;width:150px"/>
         <img id="motionS" style="visibility:hidden" src="../Downloads/leo_walk_cycle_take_two_by_luigil-d4oexx9.gif" alt= "micky-animated" style="height:10px;width:15px"/>
        <p>Click the buttons below to handle animation</p>
         <input type="button" value="Walk Micky" onclick="moveRight();" />
         <input type="button" value="Stop"   onclick="stop();" />
        </form>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it on one line? Why not do it as it's supposed to be done?

Comment: one line in the sense, apply multiple css property all at once.

Comment: Again, why? Why can't you do it sequentially like it's supposed to be done?

Comment: NO I am not getting what you are trying to convey..

Comment: It's simple: why does it need to be on one line? What is the requirement for that? You can set one, then the other and then the third. What is the problem in doing it that way?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```js
var main = document.getElementById("main");
main.style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;margin: 10px;"
```

```html
<div id="main">
```

So you would just need to change:

> document.getElementById('motionS').style.visibility="visible;height:50px;width:40px";

to

> document.getElementById('motionS').style="visibility:
>   visible;height:50px;width:40px";

Comment: Instead of applying multiple css properties.. why dont you apply class to div containing all those properties ?

Comment: @Prasad_Joshi fixed a typo (missing = after the style). it should work but as others have pointed out, you may be better using CSS classes which means you can efficiently animate the changes then if you like.

Comment: Do note that this will remove the existing styles set, not just change some of them.